# phpspreadsheet retrieve cell value as unformatted text

Tags: phpspreadsheet, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

Collect necessary rows into array ->toArray()
unseccessfully try to get unformatted text value from cell. Made the following:

```
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
```

and

```
->rangeToArray(
        'A1:Q11',   // The worksheet range that we want to retrieve
        '',      // Value that should be returned for empty cells
        FALSE,  // Should formulas be calculated (the equivalent of getCalculatedValue() for each cell)
        FALSE,  // Should values be formatted (the equivalent of getFormattedValue() for each cell)
        TRUE    // Should the array be indexed by cell row and cell column
    );
```

I get 777,7 as 777.7, but 777,77 as 777,77

Comment: Hello, have you found an answer ? If so could you update your post with it ? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @coderdonezo., unfortunatelly no, I didn't find the solution.